# Not allowed to commit an edit due to code faults

Tags: support, code-formatting, editor

## The Subject:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22390148/rpio-not-able-to-run-as-daemon

## The Error notification:

Your post appears to contain code that is not properly formatted as code. Please indent all code by 4 spaces using the code toolbar button or the CTRL+K keyboard shortcut. For more editing help, click the [?] toolbar icon.

## The flag:

I flagged this subject and got the advice to open this topic on meta if the problem remained.
"*I cannot edit this post anymore. I keep on getting this error: "Your post appears to contain code that is not properly formatted as code. Please indent all code by 4 spaces using the code toolbar button or the CTRL+K keyboard shortcut. For more editing help, click the [?] toolbar icon." The preview picks up every code perfectly, I tried translating all tabs to spaces, no result.*"

## The Attempted Modification:

I tried to alter the first two lines after the header The Error to this, as the highlighting wouldn't parse this as a comment, and the results would be the same.

```
pi@raspberrypi $ sudo  python DoorcamExample.py start
pi@raspberrypi $ ### << Returning to prompt, proving daemonizing works...
```

## The Question:

What can I do to fix this?
Is there something **I can do** to prevent this a next time, or make it work this time?
Or is this a bug and should I leave it to an operator or a moderator or even a webmaster??

Does it have a connection to being a migrated question?

## Tested conditions:

I only have Linux to mess around on, so I tried in on Firefox (my regular browser), and on Chromium. Same error message.
I tried to post it as a new question. Same error message.
I tried editing from my android phone, standard Android browser. Same error message.
I tried without the DoorcamExample.py-part. Same error message.
I tried without the 'the error'-part. Same error message.

Comment: I got it to go through (check and make sure I pasted the right thing).  Now let's figure out why.

Comment: I saw "Edited 7 mins ago, AsheeshR"so it is probably just me. Weird. One question to @AsheeshR Please could you commit my changes completely? With the change of the username included (pi@raspberrypy $. The root user always has a #, other users Never.

Comment: Thanks @jonsca . I wish I knew why, I'm still not able...

Comment: He won't get your `@` from here, but he will get it if you comment to him under your question using `@` (it won't autocomplete, but editors can be pinged that way).

Comment: What happens if you paste it into a text editor first?  It may be that you are grabbing some stray (nonprinting) characters from wherever it is being copied.

Comment: @jonsca Ah, I see, well, you corrected it so I'll let it be ;)

Comment: @jonsca I tried it in `gvim`, removing all the tabs (`%s /\t/    /g`) and looked at it, everything seemed OK...

Comment: I don't know if tabs would do that, but we'll see if someone else knows.

Comment: @jonsca I'm not sure either, but I noticed there are tabs in there. So I thought I'd give it a try. But yet I haven't been able to remove them.

Comment: That is: submit the modification without the tabs. Due to this error.